# CouchDB snappy for attachments

Tags: compression, couchdb, nosql

I am using CouchDB 1.6.1. In Futon, under Overview Configuration,  the attachments Section has a field: compression_level   8.
This looks like zlib's deflate to me, see also http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/misc.html#attachments

Under the couchdb Section, there is the field: file_compression snappy

As far as I understand, attachments are compressed with zlib and actual documents with snappy?

If so, is there a way to use snappy for attachment compression in CouchDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right: attachments are only support gzip compression while docs and other database meta information is used snappy by default (since 1.3 version). The reason why attachments are don't support snappy is pretty trivial - snappy isn't standard [content encoding algorithm](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4) and no browsers supports it while gzip is widely supported by almost every HTTP client.

So, if CouchDB stored attachments with snappy compression, it have to decode them from and encode with gzip to send back to client in the way to maintain wide compatibility. And this decode-encode operation is quite CPU expensive. All the other options leads to incompatibility with the HTTP client or again, causes operational overhead. For gzip encoding, CouchDB just sends attachments as they are stored in database file without any additional operations over their content.